# Unable to use tlmgr -gui

Tags: tlmgr

I am unable to use tlmgr -gui.

When I launch, the program launches. When I click on 'Load Default' (http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet), it does nothing.

In the terminal window that launched the command, I get errors like:

```
[Wed 31 Aug, 11:10] user:~ $ tlmgr -gui
Loading local TeX Live database
(/home/user/texlive/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb)
This may take some time, please be patient ... 
... done loading.
/home/user/texlive/tlpkg/installer/xz/x20160832 : ec.x86_64-linux: (stdin): Unexpected end of input
Tk::Error: Unknown directive ...containerchecksum                                                                         c59200574a316416a23695c258edf3a32531fbda43ccdc09360ee105c3f07f9fb77df17c4ba4c2ea4f3a5ea6667e064b51e3d8c2fe6c984ba3e71b4e32716955... , please fix it! at /home/user/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 210, <$fh> line 5579.
TeXLive::TLPOBJ::from_fh at /home/user/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 210 
TeXLive::TLPDB::from_file at /home/user/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm line 367 
TeXLive::TLPDB::new at /home/user/texlive/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPDB.pm line 148 
main::setup_one_remotetlpdb at /home/user/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr line 5872
main::_init_tlmedia at /home/user/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr line 5788
main::init_tlmedia at /home/user/texlive/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr line 5707
main::init_install_media at /home/user/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgrgui.pl line 1863
main::run_update_functions at /home/user/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgrgui.pl line 2622
main::setup_location at /home/user/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgrgui.pl line 1853
main::__ANON__ at /home/user/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/texlive/tlmgrgui.pl line 283                                      
Tk callback for .labelframe.button
Tk::__ANON__ at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Tk.pm line 251 
Tk::Button::butUp at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/Tk/Button.pm line 175 
<ButtonRelease-1>
(command bound to event)
```

What is happening? How do I set things right?

Comment: in order to run tlmg -gui you must have installed perl-tk in your system. In order to do so, you just type in your terminal `sudo apt-get install perl-tk` (i assume that you are using ubuntu)

Comment: @Yorgos, sure. perl-tk is installed. What else could it be?